# Interoperable Obj-C typedef NS_ENUM to swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, language-interoperability

In my Objective-C `.h` file, I have defined:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, RTSpinKitViewStyle) {
    RTSpinKitViewStylePlane,
    RTSpinKitViewStyleCircleFlip
};
```

How to access the enum in Swift code?

I tried using dot operator as `RTSpinKitViewStyle.RTSpinKitViewStyleCircleFlip` but it shows compile error

> "RTSpinKitViewStyle.Type does not have member type name
>   RTSpinKitViewStyleCircleFlip " .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
RTSpinKitViewStyle.CircleFlip
```

or just:

```
.CircleFlip
```

Comment: @sambhav have you added the bridge file and imported the file which contains a definitions of the enum?

Comment: Ok, i guess that error is gone . actualy now i have to invoke one function
func insertSpinnerOfStyle(style:RTSpinKitViewStyle, backgroundColor:UIColor, labelString:NSString) .
where first argument is that enum .now its showing error cannot invoke insertSpinner of style with argument of type

Answer (score 1):

You can access them as `RTSpinKitViewStyle.Plane`.

Comment: Its still shows same compile error , i have tried that earlier